# How does Maven resolve dependency conflicts?

Tags: maven

Let's assume we have a Project A.

- Project A has a dependency on Project B version 1.0
- Project A has a dependency on Project C version 2.0
- Project C (version 2.0) has a dependency on Project B version 2.0

In this case, how would Maven resolve the conflict?

Comment: I'm not satisfied the question. According to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you should "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself." I don't see any dififculties to prevent solve issue yourself.

Comment: Is this a multi module build?

Comment: @khmarbaise no. I have project B and project C as a dependency in the pom.xml of project A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd build with Project B v 1.0

You can use http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html
to see, that it omitted B 2.0 cause 1.0 is nearer.

from page above:

> by **default** Maven resolves version conflicts with a nearest-wins strategy.

Output'd be something like that:

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] Project A
[INFO] +- Project-B:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] \- Project-C:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]    \- (Project-B:jar:2.0:compile - ommited for conflicts with 1.0)
```

Comment: Old but working link: https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Answer (score 5):

I found this explanation and it was really helpful to me.

> **Nearest definition** means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the **tree of dependencies**,
>
> eg. if dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is **shorter**. You could explicitly add a dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0